# Block based on keyword

Tags: linux, proxy, squid, blocking

Hai linux guys,

I am using linux (RHEL5) Server. I want to block some sites for windows clients,

- How can i block unwanted sites based on keywords(keywords in text file) in RHEL 5 ?
- Are there any build in packages for to do this ?
- Is it possible block based on proxy (squid)?
- If possible , What i want to do for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where will these keywords exist?  If the things you want to block on are part of the URL then you can use a squid [regex acl](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#ACL_elements).

If you want to block based what makes up the content of the request you would need to be using something like [dansguardian](http://dansguardian.org/).

If you just want to use a block based on URL blacklists of a certain category you can use [squidguard](http://www.squidguard.org/) combined with one of the several blacklist databases.

Comment: if i have keyword in badkey.txt file means , how can i block sites based on it ? can you pls help me ?